# What is the Rails way of organizing unit tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testunit

When creating unit tests in a Rails project, the first question I asked myself was "what is the convention for organizing unit tests" because nearly everything else is dictated by convention. Also, I'm curious if the convention changes between MiniTest, TestUnit and Rspec.

What I have done so far is to mirror my Rails directory structure in my test/unit directory, like so:

```
[Rails Root]
 /lib/
  ./postgres.rb
  ./awesome_parser.rb
 /app/helpers
  ./psychic_helper.rb

 /test/unit/
  ./lib/postgres.rb
  ./lib/awesome_parser.rb
  ./app/helpers/psychic_helper
```

What is the most conventional way of organizing tests, so that when others hop on this project they don't curse my name?

Answer (score 5):

Rspec is like the above, except leaves out the 'app' dir, e.g. (from rails root):

```
spec/controllers/user_controller_spec.rb
spec/models/user_spec.rb
spec/helpers/user_helpers_spec.rb
```

But the lib directory and others are still used:

```
spec/lib/user_stuff_spec.rb
```

Integration tests cross boundaries, so get their own dir:

```
spec/integration/route_specs.rb
```

Spec helpers have their own dir:

```
spec/support/custom_matchers.rb
```

Probably not a convention, but we put our factories in their own dir:

```
spec/factories/user_factories.rb
```

Comment: Actually, 'spec/factories/user_factories.rb' style is a convention, its what rails w/rspec will generate when you do a 'rails generate model User'.